# Jquery AJAX Save Hierarchical Sort Add Remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

[image: 3 lists center list to accept items from right list and items from left list to go in the items from the right added to the center list]

I am looking for some sample code to follow.

I have two lists, **List1 (right)** and **List2 (left)**. Each list contains items to be joined/linked into a third list (**List3**). `List1` will load from one table, `List2` from another, and `List3` will load from a table of linked items. `List1` contains items that can have more than one match to items from `List2`. As such `List1` items are one-to-many in `List2`.

I would like to be able to drag items from `List1` to `List3` (represents the already linked items). Doing so, will create a item that items from `List2` can be dragged into (under).

E.g.

```
List1-Item1
    List2-ItemA
    List2-ItemB
```

When items are removed, I would like to trigger a call to the database to remove either the `List2,List1`-combo or if a `List1`-item is removed, then all the combos for `List1`.

Only when `List2` items are added would I like to trigger a call to the database to insert the `List1, List2`-combo.

This is going to be implemented following the MVC-pattern.

Page code here:

```
<div id="sort" style="width:1125px;">
<div id="containment">

    <div id="column1" class=" column left first" style="width: 300px; border-color: black; border:solid;">
        <ul class="sortable-list2" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li data-id="A" class="sortable-item2">
                <a href="#">
                    TEST A
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="B" class="sortable-item2">
                <a href="#">
                    TEST B
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="column3" class="column left" style="width: 300px; border-color: black; border:solid;">
        <ul class="sortable-list3" style="list-style-type: none;">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="column2" class="column left" style="width: 300px; border-color: black; border:solid;">
        <ul class="sortable-list" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li data-id="1" class="sortable-item">
                <a href="#">
                    TEST 1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="2" class="sortable-item">
                <a href="#">
                    TEST 2
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
```

//

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sort .sortable-list2").sortable({
        connectWith: '#sort .sortable-list3',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
    }).disableSelection();
    $("#sort .sortable-list").sortable({
        connectWith: '#sort .sortable-list3',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
    }).disableSelection();
    $("#sort .sortable-list3").sortable({
        connectWith: '#sort .sortable-list',
        placeholder: 'placeholder'
    }).disableSelection();
    $("#sort .sortable-list3").sortable({
        connectWith: '#sort .sortable-list2',
        placeholder: 'placeholder'
    }).disableSelection();
});
//]]>
```

Comment: currently, with the 3 lists, I am unable to get items from the left list to drop into a right list item that was dropped onto the center list.  This did work with 2 lists.  Also, once an item from the right list is dragged to the center, the item in the center cannot be dragged back to the right list.  The current code does not attempt the nesting that is required.

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle with some sample code so we can guide you in the correct direction.